# Gitlab: Automated action after merge request approval

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

A sample case is to have a hierarchy of branches, let say develop branch -> UAT branch -> master. I want each MR approval to trigger another MR, that is, merging to UAT would seamlessly create a new MR to master.

I have looked through [Gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/merge_requests.html#create-mr) and [Webhooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) but seems like they can't do this implicitly.

Besides creating a webhooks receiver to run some scripts, would it be possible to do the same but let Gitlab handle it all?